# Simulate Result set closing failed

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

How would I be able to simulate this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the CallableStatement object is closed.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsCallableStatement.checkOpen(JtdsCallableStatement.java:120)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.getConnection(JtdsStatement.java:1207)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.getConnection(JtdsResultSet.java:409)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.close(JtdsResultSet.java:470)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.close(DelegatingResultSet.java:152)
    at
```

Using a Java code.

This code below sometimes generates the error above, but sometimes does not:

```
   private void doRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ServletException {
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String someString;
        try {
            this.connectDB();
            stmt = this.conn.prepareCall("{call sp_SomeSP1(?)}");
            stmt.setLong(1, someFunc());

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                if (rs.getInt(1)==someOtherFunc()) {
                    someString = rs.getString(2);
                    break;
                }
            }

            stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call sp_someSP(?, ?)}");
            stmt.setLong(1, someFunc());
            stmt.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(getFrom().getTime()));

            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                lastUpdated = rs.getTimestamp("LastUpdated");
            }

            request.setAttribute("lastUpdated", lastUpdated);

            LOGGER.debug("Forwarding to view...");
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/SomeJSP.jsp").forward(this.request, this.response);

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Database connection lookup failed", e);
            sendError("Server Error");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Query failed", e);
            sendError("Server Error");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            LOGGER.error("View failed", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs!=null) rs.close(); 
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Result set closing failed", e);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Result set closing failed", e);
            }
            try {
                if (stmt!=null) stmt.close();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Statement closing failed", e);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Statement closing failed", e);
            }
            try {
                this.closeDB();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Database connection closing failed", e);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Database connection closing failed", e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "simulate"?

Comment: Are you trying to make method which returns ResultSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking something like this:

1. Create a prepared statement and do a query with it., getting back a result set.
2. Close the prepared statement.
3. Attempt to close the result set after closing the prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Call [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29) on `statement` before calling `execute();`

Comment: SQLException - if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed Statement. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: Well I don't have environment to test it, but as per javadoc.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR: you can't expect to get the exact same exception type and error message from a MySQL driver than the one you get with a SQLServer driver. MySQLNonTransientConnectionException extends SQLException.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/):

```
when(mockResultSet.close()).doThrow(new SQLException("Invalid state, the CallableStatement object is closed."));
```